# Changing ionicLoading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got a background in server side programming, so I'm fairly new to the Angular/Ionic framework.

I've got a small Ionic project I'm working on, where a user needs to authenticate themselves against a back end DB (I'm using Parse, for the record).

When the user hits the submit button, currently I am utilising the ionicLoading module to show a small "spinner" on screen, to show the user that something is happening:

```
$scope.loginEmail = function(){
    $scope.show($ionicLoading);
    Parse.User.logIn($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password, {success: function(user) {
```

and this is the ionicLoading being declared within the controller:

```
  $scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<p>Authenticating...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
});
};
```

I would like to re-use the ionicLoading module a few times throughout this controller (e.g. when the user clicks "Sign Up" or "Sign in With Facebook") - and even a few times throughout the app

Is there an easy way to change the "template" to display something different, depending on which button is clicked by the user?

For example:

- If the user clicks "Sign In" - the template could be set to:

  Authenticating User
- If the user clicks "Sign in with Facebook" - the template could be set to:

  Authenticating with Facebook

hope this makes sense - any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Apologies - the above "Authenticating User" and "Authenticating with Facebook" should have paragraph P tags - but I'm struggling to get them to show up in the editor!

Answer (score 0):

U may want to try this for loading, it will place the spinner in the middle of your app.

Controller:

```
.directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="img/Preloader_2.gif" /></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
      }
  })
```

Note (use this in ur controller which is bound to your selected html views to enable and disable spinner (ie, after success, change to false):

```
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.loading = false;
```

HTML:(Put at the html of ur choice)

```
<loading></loading>
```

CSS:(To place spinner in the middle)

```
.loading { position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);z-index: 9999;}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that - I guess just before i call the $scope.loading = true; can I change this line: template:'<div class="loading"><img src="img/Preloader_2.gif" /></div>', so the template is different depending on where in my app I am calling it from?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead and change the img src, but retain the div class part as it is needed for the <loading></loading>